# What db operations are possible in mongodb triggers?

Tags: mongodb

I consider using mongo db triggers for some data maintenance.
I will need to:

- rename collection
- create new collection
- copy index from one collection to another

Is it possible using triggers?
I couldn't find it yet in the documentation.

Comment: Mongo DB does not support triggers as far as I know. Note, if you try to insert data into a non-existing collection then the collection is created automatically.

Comment: Hi @WernfriedDomscheit, thanks for the response. I meant Mongo Atlas/Realm triggers - https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/triggers/.
I am aware of collection being created automatically, but some indexes I want to be included from the beginning.